# Cannot change labels' titles after localizing story board

Tags: ios, localization, uistoryboard, localizable.strings

I'm new to this localization thing. I am trying to localize my storyboard into Chinese. So I have my storyboard setup like so:

[image]

I have translated the strings in the (Tradtional) chinese strings file. This all works. However when I make changes to the storyboard now the changes aren't reflected when I run it on the device. For example if I change the title of a label in the storyboard and then run it, the label will remain the same. Why is this happening? If I reposition labels etc that seems to work, but changing the title doesn't. My second question is, what storyboard should I be editing now? The original one, or the one below it that says Storyboard.storyboard (Base) ?

Answer (score 0):

For ideal way, you have to edit your Main storyboard (without BASE), and based on localised string setting, your other localised storyboard will get update.

If you directly change title of the localised storyboard, it will misses the reference of Main storyboard, so couldn't reflect the auto-change of language while running.